# Preloading templates with Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

i made a little app, which shows base64 encoded images with some text underneath. I use iScroll for the scrolling and Handlebars.js for the screen templates.

My problem is, that sometimes the iScroll.refresh() method is called too early and won't calculate the right dimensions.

```
app.dataInterface.getContents(self.gameid, self.state, function(contents){
    self.currentContents = contents;
    for (i=0; i<contents.length; i++) {
        $(IngameView.cimgtemplate(contents[i])).hide().appendTo(".content").fadeIn();
    }
    self.setScroll();
    });
```

The handlebars template:

```
<script id="content-img-tpl" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="contents content_img" id="{{content_id}}">
            <img class="image" src="{{src}}"/>
            {{txt}}
        </div>
</script>
```

I'm not quite sure about if handlebars works synchronous or not, but since it works when the image data is small I think it might be a problem with the image loading (being decoded) too slow.

**Is there any way to preload Handlebars.js templates before attaching them to the DOM or to have some kind of callback to refresh after the Handlebars-helpers have been executed and images loaded?**

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you compile your Handlebars template but here is how I've solved the issue by using a generic template compiling function with a custom json request :

```
function initTemplate(jsonWS, templateName, callback){
$.ajax({
    url: jsonWS,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'field-action': 'select', 'jquery-list': templateName },
    success: function(data){
        var templateScript = $('#' + templateName).html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(templateScript); 
        $('.' + templateName).html(template(data)); 
    },
    complete: function(){
        if(callback != null) callback();
    },
    error: function(data){
        notify(data.responseText);
    }
});
}
```

If you want to make sure your data has loaded before playing with it, pass a callback function which will be called only when the template will have been fully rendered.